# Estimate $\int f\:{\rm d}\lambda$ and $\int g\:{\rm d}\mu$, where whenever $(X,Y)\sim\mu$, then $X\sim\lambda$, by a single Markov chain

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, unbiased-estimator, metropolis-hastings

Say I want to estimate $$I=\int f\:{\rm d}\lambda+\int g\:{\rm d}\mu.$$ Now, I'm using Metropolis-Hastings to sample from $\lambda$ and from $\mu$, separately. Assume $\mu$ is defined on a product space and whenever $(X,Y)\sim\mu$, then $X\sim\lambda$.

My question is: Instead of constructing Markov chains $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ and $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ using the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with target distribution $\lambda$ and $\mu$, respectively, and use these chains to build independent estimators for both integrals on the right-hand side of the definition of $I$, would there be any drawback (for example, higher variance) if I only compute $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$, which is of the form $((X_n,Y_n))_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$, and use $$\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(f(X_i)+g(X_i,Y_i))$$ as an estimator for $I$?

Comment: The latter is valid as the correlation between $f(X_i)$ and $g(X_i,Y_i)$ does not impact convergence.